# How can we get Images from Sitefinity Content Images to Widget Designer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitefinity

I would like to have images that the user uploads in the backend Content/Images to be available in a specific widget designer.

I'm Working with Sitefinity 8.1 and all my widgets are MVC Widgets.

Anyone have implemented something like this? is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller add a public property of type Guid. Build. Use Thunder to create a designer for existing widget. I usually create another folder in the MVC called designers then one folder in there for each widget. Then using thunder you can make that Guid field an Image selector.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I saw a some related posts but they wasn't clear. cheers